# Want to save a PDF file from C# code in a specific folder

Tags: c#

I am trying to save a PDF file in a specific folder using C#. But, the file is always being saved in D: drive instead of D:\PO(PO is the folder inside D Drive).
I want the file to be saved inside the PO folder. The code is:

```
string fName = @"D:\PO\" + VendorName + "-" + woid + ".pdf";
```

Comment: please share the codes you have on saving the pdf

Comment: @Arnel Aves: Actually the code is quite big and the PDF is saved properly with all the information, the problem is with the file path and I am not able to save it inside the PO folder

Comment: first what is the `verndorname`, how is the value generated, second, it is better to see the actual **saving** code block, where you used the `fName` variable

Comment: @psdif post the *relevant* code. For all one can guess, you are *not* using `fName` to save the file or `VendorName` starts with `..\\`. You shouldn't need to post more than 2 lines of code

Comment: Did you try debugging? What path do you get in fName?

Comment: I figured it out. I was not using the fName variable :-) and thanx all of you for giving help and @PanagiotisKanavos- You were right! Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Give the path like :
Path.Combine(@"F:\pft\activityobjids\DEV\Jan\Part1", ObjId + ".txt")